# No rear running or brake lights Zafira B

Tags: lights, zafira

Hi I’ve got an issue with my 57 Zafira  1.9 diesel. I have no rear running lights or main cluster brake lights. My top tailgate brake light works  as do my indicators, reverse lights and rear fogs. I’ve checked all the bulbs and they are fine. I’ve seen other mentions of this on forums but as usual nobody ever posts the solution. I’m really stuck as I need to get this sorted by tomorrow evening. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the fuses?